# JavaScript - can't see information posted via edit form without refreshing

Tags: javascript

I have an SPA i'm working on right now that uses Rails for backend and JavaScript for front end. Currently, upon submitting the initial form I have to fill out a Resource, it appears on the page immediately when the submit button is pressed. I also have an edit form, but in order to see the updated Resource, I have to refresh the page.

What can I do to make it so the updated Resources updates on the page without refreshing?

index.js

```
const materialIndex = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/materials"
const categoryIndex = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/categories"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    getMaterials()

    const createMaterialForm = document.querySelector("#create-material-form")

    createMaterialForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => createFormHandler(e))

    const materialContainer = document.querySelector('#material-container')
    materialContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //debugger
        const id = parseInt(e.target.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id)
        const material = Material.findById(id)
        document.querySelector('#edit-material').innerHTML = material.renderPatchForm()
        console.log(material)
    })
    document.querySelector('#edit-material').addEventListener('submit', e => updateForm(e))
})

function getMaterials() {
    fetch(materialIndex) //get request
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(materials => {
        materials.data.forEach(material => {
            let newMaterial = new Material(material, material.attributes)
            //creating new instance of material class, goes to constructor and gets pushed into an array
            document.querySelector('#material-container').innerHTML += newMaterial.renderMaterialCard()
        })
        // want to create category cards, where each resource populates in each category card once added //
    })
}

function createFormHandler(e) { //grabs all values of materials submitted by user
    e.preventDefault()
    const nameInput = document.querySelector('#input-name').value
    const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#input-description').value
    const urlInput = document.querySelector('#input-url').value
    const categoryId = parseInt(document.querySelector('#categories').value)
    postFetch(nameInput, descriptionInput, urlInput, categoryId)
}

function updateForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const id = parseInt(e.target.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id)
    const material = Material.findById(id)
    const name = e.target.querySelector('#input-name').value
    const description = e.target.querySelector('#input-description').value
    const url = e.target.querySelector('#input-url').value
    const category_id = parseInt(e.target.querySelector('#categories').value)
    patchMaterial(material, name, description, url, category_id)
}

function postFetch(name, description, url, category_id) {
    const bodyData = {name, description, url, category_id}
    fetch(materialIndex, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(material => {
        const materialData = material.data
        let newMaterial = new Material(materialData, materialData.attributes)
        document.querySelector('#material-container').innerHTML += newMaterial.renderMaterialCard()
    })
}

function patchMaterial(material, name, description, url, category_id) {
    const patchJSON = {name, description, url, category_id}
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/materials/${material.id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(patchJSON),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(material => {
        const materialData = material.data
        //debugger
        let newMaterial = Material(materialData, materialData.attributes)
        document.querySelector('#material-container').innerHTML += newMaterial.renderMaterialCard()
    })
}
```

material.js

```
class Material {
    constructor(material, materialAttributes) {
        this.id = material.id
        this.name = materialAttributes.name
        this.description = materialAttributes.description
        this.url = materialAttributes.url
        this.category = materialAttributes.category
        Material.all.push(this)
    }

    renderMaterialCard() {
        return `
            <div data-id=${this.id}>
            <h3>${this.name}</h3>
            <p>${this.description}</p>
            <p><small><a href="${this.url}">${this.url}</a></small></p>
            <p>${this.category.title}</p>
            <button data-id=${this.id}>edit</button>
            </div>
            <br><br>`
    }

    static findById(id) {
        return this.all.find(material => material.id == id)
    }


    renderPatchForm() {
        return `
            <form data-id=${this.id} >
                <h2>Edit the Resource</h2>

                <label>Name</label>
                <input id='input-name' type="text" name="name" value="${this.name}" class="input-name">
                <br><br>

                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea id='input-description' name="description" rows="8" cols="80" value="">${this.description}</textarea>
                <br><br>

                <label>URL</label>
                <input id='input-url' type="text" name="url" value="${this.url}" class="input-text">
                <br><br>

                <label>Category</label>
                <select id="categories" name="categories" value="${this.category.name}">
                    <option value="1">Criminal Justice Reform</option>
                    <option value="2">Bail Funds</option>
                    <option value="3">Clothing</option>
                    <option value="4">Organizations</option>
                    <option value="5">Mutual Aid</option>
                    <option value="6">Fundraisers</option>
                    <option value="7">Petitions</option>
                    <option value="8">Articles</option>
                    <option value="9">Artists</option>
                    <option value="10">Instagram</option>
                </select>
                <br><br>

                <input id='edit-button' type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Resource" class="submit">
            </form> `
  }
}

Material.all = []
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Beneficial Resources</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/material.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>A Space For Resources</h1>
        <h5>An open space that hosts resources dedicated to urgent issues around the World.</h5>
        </center>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form id="create-material-form">
                <h2>Add a new Resource</h2>

                <input id='input-name' type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Resource Name" class="input-text">
                <br><br>
                <textarea id='input-description' name="description" rows="8" cols="80" value="" placeholder="Enter the description of your Resource..."></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <input id="input-url" type="text" name="url" value="" placeholder="URL" class="input-text">
                <br>

                <h4>What Category is your Resource?</h4>
                <select id="categories" name="categories">
                    <option value="1">Criminal Justice Reform</option>
                    <option value="2">Bail Funds</option>
                    <option value="3">Clothing</option>
                    <option value="4">Organizations</option>
                    <option value="5">Mutual Aid</option>
                    <option value="6">Fundraisers</option>
                    <option value="7">Petitions</option>
                    <option value="8">Articles</option>
                    <option value="9">Artists</option>
                    <option value="10">Instagram</option>
                </select>
                <br>

                <input id="create-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add New Resource" class="submit">

            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>

        <div id="edit-material">

        </div>

        <div id="material-container">

        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `console.log(materialData);` inside `postFetch`. What do you see?

Comment: Off-topic warning: [The `<center>` element was deprecated in HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) (that is, since 1999). Consider replacing with a `<div>` or other element and CSS to center the text.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using this approach? Rails can handle the form submission and updates quite easily without resorting to using javascript in the way you have done it (?) - see here (for a crude example): https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements - you can also return a javascript so that it updates your page on form submission so that you don't have to press the refresh button to see those updated changes. Consider everything that is in that link carefully.

Answer (score 0):

#### One problem: Event handler for the patch form is added before the patch form is added to the dom

I suspect the problem is that your event hander: `document.querySelector('#edit-material').addEventListener('submit', e => updateForm(e))` for the update form, must be added AFTER the update form has been added to the DOM. There may be other issues, but this will hopefully get you a step closer towards your goal:

```
const materialContainer = document.querySelector('#material-container')
    materialContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
        //debugger
        const id = parseInt(e.target.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id)
        const material = Material.findById(id)
        document.querySelector('#edit-material').innerHTML = material.renderPatchForm()
        console.log(material) // Add the line below
        document.querySelector('#edit-material').addEventListener('submit', e => updateForm(e)) // <------ Add this line here!!
    })
    //// document.querySelector('#edit-material').addEventListener('submit', e => updateForm(e)) // remove this line from here
```

#### Use the rails defaults

You don't need to render a `renderPatchForm` inline using javascript - why not just  use plain old html and ruby? Consider also some of the ideas outlined here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements.